# How do I use Pango.AttrType.FOREGROUND in Python and Gtk3?

Tags: python, python-2.7, gtk3, pango

I am replacing some PyGtk code that looks like this :

`pango.AttrForeground(65535, 0, 0, 0, 100)`

Translating that to Gtk3 looks like this :

`Pango.AttrType.FOREGROUND(65535, 0, 0, 0, 100)`

However I get the error `TypeError: 'AttrType' object is not callable`. Googling seems to bring no results or then I searched for the wrong thing. Any ideas? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking [in the old PyGTK code](https://github.com/GNOME/pygtk/blob/eaf1c1b881d2d20d202cf475b5ffed2206b110df/pango.defs#L86) it seems that `pango.AttrForeground()` wrapped the function `pango_attr_foreground_new()`. This function is marked non-introspectable in the GIR bindings, so it won't be available in the new Python libraries. I don't know the reason why; presumably there is some other way to do what the old code did.

Comment: Thanks for giving me this heads up. I also feel there is a replacement somewhere / somehow. For now I have commented out this line and will keep my eyes open for the replacement. Maybe when I figure out what the original code did, things will become easier. Thanks again.